# Please help me identify this jelly fish

Tags: species-identification, classification

I've seen these jellyfish in thailand and was wondering what species they were. All I know is that there are lot in the Chonburi area and they sting in not deadly but hurts.

[Images for the jellyfish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKcNA.jpg)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Those pictures don’t look like a complete jellyfish, which makes identification *very* hard. Also, there’s no sense of scale in the pictures - can you describe them in more detail since you were there to see them personally?

Comment: Well the bigger ones are around 15-25 cm tall (in water the ones I could see at least) and around 10-15 in diameter. I don't know if they are complete or not I could only see there are also one smaller which was around 10cm in height and 5 in diameter with a similar structure. Well they are hardly noticeable in water because the water is not too clean so I couldn't take picture in the water.  Also there are some people eating them on the shore. And their sting also leaves red lines like other jellyfish sting and usually hurts for around 15 minutes (asked others who were sting before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a [Rhizostomae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhizostomae), or crown jellyfish, but it's hard to tell. The  article [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/275936948_Synopsis_of_edible_jellyfishes_collected_from_Southeast_Asia_with_notes_on_jellyfish_fisheries) does mention that it's edible though and it's found in Thailand so I'm pretty happy with that guess.

More specifically, it looks similar to the jellyfish asked about [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Can_anybody_help_identify_this_jellyfish_from_the_Gulf_of_Thailand), which was eventually classified as a *Lobonemoides*, perhaps *Lobonemoides robusta*